# The session expires in springboot project

Tags: java, spring

The session expiration time set does not work in springboot application.properties file with 'server.session.timeout' field.No matter how long the settings expire, they expire in a very short period of time.What caused this setting to fail and what can I do to fix it.

Comment: `server.session.timeout` is deprecated now. The latest version of SpringBoot [SpringDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) is using the following properties : `server.servlet.session.timeout=30m`

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try to modify it like this.